# Como fazer para deixar o mapa do Google dinâmico

Tags: html, ajax, json, web-service, google-maps

Estou criando um app de monitoramento de carros e estou com um problema, estou tentando fazer com que o mapa se atualize dinamicamente sem a necessidade de ficar atualizando a pagina manualmente, essa pagina recebe a localização através de um arquivo .json no código estou chamando um arquivo, mas as informações virão através de um Web Service onde recebe informações de localização através de GPS, alguém teria ideia de como faço para deixar essa pagina dinâmica?

[image: Como seria a pagina de monitoramento]

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <meta name="googlebot" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/result-light.css">
  <style type="text/css">
    #map_canvas { width: 1000px; height: 600px; }

  </style>

  <title></title>
  <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
$(window).load(function(){
var gMapsLoaded = false;
window.gMapsCallback = function(){
    gMapsLoaded = true;
    $(window).trigger('gMapsLoaded');
}
window.loadGoogleMaps = function(){
    if(gMapsLoaded) return window.gMapsCallback();
    var script_tag = document.createElement('script');
    script_tag.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
    script_tag.setAttribute("src","http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=gMapsCallback");
    (document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.documentElement).appendChild(script_tag);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    function initialize(){
        //Aqui cria a varivel para o mapa
        var myLatLng = {lat: -23.001066, lng: -43.421180};
        var pos = {lat: -23.001271, lng: -43.329061};

        var image = 'img/car2.png';


        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 15,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(-23.001066, -43.421180),  //-23.001066, -43.421180
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP};
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),mapOptions);  
             $.getJSON('igreja.json', function(data) { //igreja.json //endereco1.json
                  //var output="<ul>";

                  var mark;
                  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

                  for (var i in data) {
                     mark = new google.maps.Marker({
                           position: new google.maps.LatLng(data[i].latitude, data[i].longitude),
                           map: map,
                           icon: image
                      });

                     mark.addListener('click', function() {
                      map.setZoom(15);
                      map.setCenter(mark.getPosition());

                       infowindow.setContent(data[i].nome);//data[i].latitude, data[i].longitude
                      infowindow.open(map, mark);
                    });

                  }
            });
    }

    $(window).bind('gMapsLoaded', initialize);
    window.loadGoogleMaps();
});
});//]]> 

</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="map_canvas"></div>
<div id="debug"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Considerou chamar o `initialize()` varias vezes com `setInterval`, só vai precisar limpar os **markers** cada vez que entrar nessa função

Comment: Jhonatan, essa é a forma correta de se fazer ou possui outra forma?

Comment: Para analisar melhor, precisava do conteudo de `igreja.json` dai poderia avaliar e entender melhor o contexto.

Comment: Esse é o json: [
   {
      "nome":"Abound",
      "latitude":"-23.001075",
      "longitude":"-43.421170"
   },
   {
      "nome":"Barra sul",
      "latitude":"-23.005563",
      "longitude":"-43.430661"
     
   }
]

Comment: Mano fiz uma brincadeira e deu certo... veja ai: http://credlocaliza.com.br/sistema/teste.php , claro que o mover do ponteiro não está sequencial em uma rua, mais vai mudando aleatoriamente. Utilizei setInterval a cada 3 segundos, mais dá para aumentar isso

Comment: ficou muito bom isso mesmo que preciso, você poderia me passar o código de exemplo que utilizou?

Comment: Vou passar sim... mudei um pouco seu código para funcionar para mim...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segue código:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
    <meta name="googlebot" content="noindex, nofollow">
    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
        .map_canvas {
            width: 1000px;
            height: 600px;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="contexto_canvas">
        <div class="map_canvas"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="debug"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function initialize(){
            //Aqui cria a varivel para o mapa
            var myLatLng = {lat: -23.001066, lng: -43.421180};
            var pos = {lat: -23.001271, lng: -43.329061};

            var image = 'https://www.iconfinder.com/icons/285810/auto_automobile_car_sedan_vehicle_icon#size=64';

            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 15,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(-23.001066, -43.421300),  //-23.001066, -43.421180
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

            var div_canvas = document.createElement("div");
            div_canvas.setAttribute("class", "map_canvas");
            $(".contexto_canvas").append(div_canvas);

            map = new google.maps.Map(div_canvas,mapOptions);  

            $.getJSON('igreja.json', function(data) {
                // Codigo para não usar cache do servidor
                $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false});
                var mark;
                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

                for (var i in data) {
                    console.log(data[i]);
                    mark = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(data[i].latitude, data[i].longitude),
                        map: map,
                        title: data[i].nome
                    });
                }
            });

            $($(".map_canvas")[0]).remove();
        }

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false});
            initialize();
            // Código para executar a cada 3000 milisegundos
            setInterval( initialize, 3000);
        });

    </script>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Jhonatan vai me ajudar muito.